# Connecting hc-05(bluetooth) with clicker2 with STM32(ARM)

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, uart, bluetooth, board

For a school project I a got HC-05 bluetooth module and MikroE Clicker2 with STM32 (ARM).

When I connect and use module with Arduino, 9600 BAUD rate and all other settings used with SoftwareSerial work and module properly communicates with my Android device.

Once I connect HC-05 with clicker, on some of UART ports(there are 4 on my board), communication works but data is corrupted. Actually data is always composed of same values (exact value is 192).

Both sending and receiving work, module is properly connected rx/tx tx/rx, but data is always equal to same value.

Any idea what can cause said data corruption? Since it works on Arduino I am sure its not between module and android device.

Comment: The UART settings are exactly the same on the Arduino and the Clicker?

Comment: Hey, yes they are: 
Arduino:
`SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); BTserial.begin(9600); `


Clicker2(MikroC)
`UART3_Init_Advanced(9600, _UART_8_BIT_DATA, _UART_NOPARITY, _UART_ONE_STOPBIT, &_GPIO_MODULE_USART3_PD89);`


HC-05: 
`AT+UART?` returns 9600,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem, solution was to edit project configuration in MikroC IDE, there were few premade schemes that i tried and one of them worked, everything works great now.

Project configuration can be changed from Project -> Edit Project and there will
"Load Scheme" button on right. There by default it will show you few premade schemes, select one for your microprocessor.